# Entity Framework not refreshing the database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I need to update old path in the database to the new one. When I run the code, I can see the new path updates in the database but when I try to get it from the database, I get back the old path (like I didn't change it).

```
public void UpdateReportPath(string oldPath,string newPath)
{
    using (var context = new Db())
    {
        var reports = context.Report.Where(r => r.ReportId > 0).ToList();

        foreach (var report in reports)
        {
            report.ReportFullPath = report.ReportFullPath.Replace(oldPath, newPath);
        }

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Other place in the code

```
var fullPath = Report.ReportFullPath;     // I get old path
```

Comment: Could you include the "other place" in code as well? Is `Report` a property?

Comment: public partial class Report : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public string ReportFullPath {            get;            set; }

Comment: I guess I need to mark that my entity state is changes and refresh it because I update content of db

Comment: If you see it update in the database then it had to be in a modified state. Does it pull the old path while still running or after you restart the application? (side note, don't `ToList()` the result, its a waste)

Comment: After restart the application the path is ok. What about ToList()?

Comment: If you have cached the Report object in memory, (I.e. a reference property) or have loaded the Report in a different context that has it cached, then changes to the reports in this context (and database) will not automatically be refreshed to cached references.

Comment: You should show more code than just `var fullPath = Report.ReportFullPath;`. When/where do you execute that statement?

Comment: You can _refresh_ it: `context.Entity(Report).Reload()`